# Сортировка списка IP адресов python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Дан список ip адресов вида

```
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
37.19.92.67
192.168.1.3
192.168.1.4
17.27.48.13
192.168.1.5
27.14.93.56
192.168.1.6
192.168.1.7
1.1.1.1
123.123.123.123
222.222.222.222
```

Нужно преобразовать его в список вида:

```
192.168.1.0/29
37.19.92.67
17.27.48.13
27.14.93.56
1.1.1.1
123.123.123.123
222.222.222.222
```

Как это можно сделать на языке Python?

Comment: Добавте описание кретерии  отбора. 192.168.1.1/29?

Comment: 192.168.1.7 попадает под маску /29 почему же его нет в списке, но принято решение записать всю подсеть /29

Comment: @Mike Спасибо, исправил

Comment: Нашел пример с модулем netaddr https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24626077/summarize-very-long-list-of-ipv4-addresses-in-python проверил `print(cidr_merge([ IPAddress(x) for x in lst ]))` (где ist массив с вашими адресами). Он конечно работает но собирает совсем честные блоки. А по этой причине он не выдает /29 если в списке не окажется адреса 192.168.1.0 (потому что он то же попадает под маску, хотя мы и не привыкли, что 0 на конце допустим). документация https://netaddr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial_01.html

Comment: как вариант решения данной проблемы вижу например пройтись предварительно по массиву и для всех адресов с .1 на конце добавить еще адреса с .0 на конце. Если такой подход считаете допустимым для вашей конечной цели

Comment: И может быть даже сделать .255 для всех .254  Если броадкаст адреса не пугают

Comment: И кстати да, еще одна ошибка в требованиях. в результате должно быть конечно 192.168.1.0/29 а не 1.1/29

Comment: @Mike, спасибо, это то, что нужно.

Comment: покапал матчасть немного и видится мне решение на python версии 3.10. ТС, версия приемлима?

Comment: @Dmitry Не понял причем тут версии языка. Алгоритм не столько сложный, сколько муторный. Реализовать на чем угодно можно. Да и библиотека найденная вроде не требовательна к версии

Comment: @Mike раз решение найдено, напишу для себя. Разберу, закреплю, критику послушаю. В новой версии появился метод подсчета бит в интовых числах, попробую его использовать, int.bit_count()